# How to replace the contents of a group with a regular expression

Tags: java, regex

This is the original string:

`233<C:\Users\Grapes\Documents\title.png>233<C:\Users\Grapes\Documents\title.png>33`

This is the replaced string I want:
`233<1>233<2>33`

I want to replace the file path in the string with the id I got after uploading to the server, but my program is in an infinite loop.

```java
public void sendMessage(String msg) {
    new Thread(()-> {
        var pat = Pattern.compile("<(.*?[^\\\\])>");
        var matcher = pat.matcher(msg);
        int k = 0;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            matcher.replaceFirst("<" + k++ + ">"));
        }
        System.out.println(msg);
    }).start();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use `Matcher#appendReplacement`:

```
String s = "233<C:\\Users\\Grapes\\Documents\\title.png>233<C:\\Users\\Grapes\\Documents\\title.png>33";
int k = 0;
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("<[^<>]*>").matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(result, "<" + ++k + ">");
}
m.appendTail(result);
System.out.println(result.toString());
// => 233<1>233<2>33
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/W8RSj4).

The `<[^<>]*>` pattern is enough in your case as it will match `<`, then any 0 or more chars other than `<` and `>` and then `<`.